# python network packet analyising using dpkt

Tags: python, pcap

I'm trying to analyze a SCTP *.pcap file captured by `tcpdump` using `dpkt` library in python.

I'm able to get SCTP common header, chunk header. After the chunk header, I'm getting a `chunk.data` which can't be parsed using the library. (i went through the source code).

However I need only the 1st 4 bytes of that `chunk.data`. The type of the `chunk.data` is string. So I thought, if I can get 1st 4 characters, I can get the 1st 4 bytes (since size of a character is 1 byte). After that I need to convert those 4 bytes to host byte order using `socket.ntohl()`. But 1st I need to convert the 4 character string to an unsigned integer to be given as input to the `socket.ntohl()` function which I don't know how to do.

I tried taking the ascii code.

```
data=chunk.data
x=data[:4]
i= ntohl(int(''.join(str(ord(c)) for c in x)))
```

It's showing an error:

```
i= ntohl(int(''.join(str(ord(c)) for c in x)))
OverflowError: long int too large to convert
```

I tried by taking `x="efgh"`. But the ascii value will not generate a 4 byte unsigned integer. (101102103104 > 4294967295) So I think ascii value is not the correct one to use here.

Can anyone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @BSH for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155437/pointer-typecasting-like-c-in-python).

I added

```
from struct import unpack
```

and for my required output, this works fine for me.

```
i=ntohl(unpack('<I',chunk.data[:4])[0])
```

[struct.unpack](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/struct.html) is used for interpreting string as packed binary data.