# pointer typecasting like c in python

Tags: python, pointers, casting

I've a c code to type cast a string to an integer via pointer.

```
char s[]="efgh";
int * p;
p=(int *) s;
printf("%d",*p);
```

This gives me an output of:

```
1751606885
```

Which is a 32 bit integer.

I'm analyzing a network packet in python and need the above functionality in python. 
I've a string

```
s="efgh"
```

and want the above in a 32 bit integer (from the byte level).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html):

```
>>> import struct
>>>
>>> struct.unpack('<I', 'efgh')
(1751606885,)
>>>
```

Comment: Is there any option to get that value in unsigned int. for my network analysis implementation, I'm getting a negative number. But i need an unsigned one. and can anyone tell me what is happening here?

Comment: @RatDon Use `I` instead of `i`, read about [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).